# Identical code slower than JS closure library equivalent

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-library

I wanted to create a binary search algorithm with some modifications.  So I grabbed the code from Google's closure library and started making these modifications.  My modified version seemed slower than it should be so I slowly took out anything I thought could be affecting the speed.  What I was left with is a SIMPLER version of the binary search algorithm and it was still several times slower in both Chrome or firefox.  What could be causing this?  Take a look at this test page.  Inspect the source to see what I'm talking about.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4hhuq4biznv1jfd/SortedArrayTest.html

This is google's version.

```
goog.array.binarySearch_ = function(arr, compareFn, isEvaluator, opt_target,
    opt_selfObj) {
  var left = 0;  // inclusive
  var right = arr.length;  // exclusive
  var found;
  while (left < right) {
    var middle = (left + right) >> 1;
    var compareResult;
    if (isEvaluator) {
      compareResult = compareFn.call(opt_selfObj, arr[middle], middle, arr);
    } else {
      compareResult = compareFn(opt_target, arr[middle]);
    }
    if (compareResult > 0) {
      left = middle + 1;
    } else {
      right = middle;
      // We are looking for the lowest index so we can't return immediately.
      found = !compareResult;
    }
  }
  // left is the index if found, or the insertion point otherwise.
  // ~left is a shorthand for -left - 1.
  return found ? left : ~left;
};
```

This is my version:

```
        var search = function(array, num){
            var left = 0;  // inclusive
            var right = array.length;  // exclusive
            while (left < right) {
                var middle = (left + right) >> 1;
                var midValue = array[midValue];
                if (num > midValue) {
                    left = middle + 1;
                } else {
                    right = middle;
                }
            }
            return left;
        };
```

Since people seem to think its something with the comparefn function...when you don't provide a comparer function to the binarySearch method it uses the following default compare function:

```
    goog.array.defaultCompare = function(a, b) {
      return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    };

    goog.array.binarySearch = function(arr, target, opt_compareFn) {
  return goog.array.binarySearch_(arr,
      opt_compareFn || goog.array.defaultCompare, false /* isEvaluator */,
      target);
};
```

Please don't respond without looking at the code.  Guesses aren't very helpful.

Comment: Try posting a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) demo to show the difference in performance

Comment: The Google code is getting the data from `compareFn` that it uses to set either left or right, your code is getting the data from an array, and something tells me your code is doing a lot more iterations in the while loop. Place a counter inside the loop to see how many times it runs in each while loop.

Comment: @adeneo compareFn just returns 1 or 0 depending on if the number is greater than or less than the middle value.  I just compare the number to the middle value direclty

Comment: The code is pretty simple, and if your version is a lot slower than Google's version, it's most likely the while loop doing more iterations, and the only way for that to happen is if the data compared is different. You have to debug this somehow.

Comment: my guess are the calls to the compareFn methods which yield back a result that allows CompareResult to increment left. thus faster while return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation contains a bug. It contains:

```
var midValue = array[midValue]
```

which should be

```
var midValue = array[middle]
```

instead.

Apparently, your were unlucky enough for your data set not to expose the bug as an incorrect result, but just as a performance problem.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!  I can't believe it was such stupid mistake!  I never actually checked that it was returning the right indexes!  I checked to make sure the arrays were sorted accurately but that didn't tell me anything because I wasn't even using my search algorithm to do the sorting. Doh!